# Data validation to allow users to enter a date (between ranges) OR N/A only

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I would like to set data validation on a column, (say L), so that users can only input a date (between ranges) or N/A.  I don't want any other entries to be allowed.  I can do one or the other, but don't know how to do both.  I guess it is in Custom, but have no clue what the formula should read to make this happen.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=OR(AND(L1<=DATE(2017,12,31),L1>=DATE(2017,1,1)),L1 = "N/A")
```

Change the dates to the beginning and end, and change `L1` to the upper left cell of the range you are applying the data validation.